# Twitter Search API - NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: jquery, json, twitter, http-status-code-405

I was following this tutorial on how to parse twitter search api requests with jquery.

http://webhole.net/2009/11/28/how-to-read-json-with-javascript/

The code in the post uses a search box for the user to enter the search term and what I simply wanted to do was remove the search part since I know the #tag that I want to search for:

```
<div id="results"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url='http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=';
    var query='%23HASHTAGOFMYCHOOSING';
    var options='&result_type=recent&count=5';

    $.getJSON(url+query+options,function(json){
        $.each(json.results,function(i,tweet){
        $("#results").append('<p><img src="'+tweet.profile_image_url+'" width="48" height="48" />'+tweet.text+'</p>');
        });
    });
});
```

The error I am getting in Firebug is `NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed` and I was just wondering if anyone could shine some light as to why I've broken this code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah, the problem was that I was missing the `callback` parameter so the `options` variable should read as follows:

```
var options='&result_type=recent&count=5&callback=?';
```