# "405 Method not allowed" - when using ASP.NET jQuery ajax POST

Tags: asp.net, jquery, post, http-status-code-405

I've searched through loads of different existing SO questions related to a similar issue, but I've not been able to find anything relevant to my issue.

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "Index.aspx/DeclineRequest"
   , type: 'POST'
   , contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
   , dataType: 'json'
   , data: JSON.stringify({ RequestId: requestId })
});
```

I'm using a very similar technique to POST data on another ASP.NET web application, and this works fine. However, this application is returning the following error:

> "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://localhost:57255/....."

I can't find anything different about these 2 applications, so I'm confused as to why this isn't working.

This only difference between these 2 applications which I can think of, is that the one that is working is .NET 2.0, and the one that isn't working is .NET 3.5.

I've tried adding the following to my `web.config`, but I still get the same 405 error:

```
<webServices>
   <protocols>
     <add name="HttpPost"/>     
     <add name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>   
   </protocols>      
</webServices>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

**UPDATE (16:40):** I've moved this application to IIS, and the 405 error is no longer being returned. Our development environment however is localhost only. Why would this only error on localhost?

Comment: Can you show us your'e `DeclineRequest` method?

Comment: Is it similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430492/twitter-search-api-networkerror-405-method-not-allowed??

Comment: @ŁukaszW.pl `DeclineRequest` method is simply calling `return "Hello World"` at the moment. I don't think this is the issue as typing any method name returns the same error. I've deliberately misspelt the method in some tests to check this.

Answer (score 1):

> 405 errors often arise with the POST method. You may be trying to introduce some kind of input form on the Web site, but not all ISPs allow the POST method necessary to process the form.
>
> All 405 errors can be traced to configuration of the Web server and security governing access to the content of the Web site, so should easily be explained by your ISP.

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

I would turn IIS Logging on to check requests. Also get Fiddler to see what is going on behind the scenes

Comment: I'm just doing this through `localhost` at the moment using VS 2010, so I don't have any IIS Logging.

Comment: I have seen a lot of inconsistencies between the ways IIS and VS work. I'd try setting up IIS host and go from there.

Comment: This is working fine for my other application though, running on the same machine, with almost identical code. So installing IIS doesn't seem like the solution.

Comment: okay. But you can still get Fiddler and examine request/response

Comment: I've downloaded fiddler but it's not really telling me much more than FireBug does

Comment: contentTypeString
Default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

When sending data to the server, use this content-type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", which is fine for most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late to the party but, try adding to your Web.Config file:

```
< handlers >
   ....
       < remove name="WebDAV" />
   ....
< /handlers >
```

This article explains what could be causing the problem:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications

Answer (score 0):

url: "Index.aspx/DeclineRequest" shouldn't be url: "Index.aspx?DeclineRequest" should it?

Sorry for the rather obvious suggestion, I've not seen a url like that before. You are rewriting it?

Comment: That's a WebMethod call format that calls DeclineRequest method defined in Index.aspx codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

check the request ur sending to the server 
the parameters to declineRequest is a object with a property of `RequesId` OR
a `string`(or some other datatype) name `RequestId`
cuz in the latter case u can just send data as `JSON` or a plain string like `RequestId=requestId`
so try replacing `JSON.stringify({ RequestId: requestId })` with something more appropriate

Comment: Even without sending any parameters, I get the same issue

Comment: what exactly is he TYPE of the parameter there? is it some non nullable type?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is: In the request you are saying that returned content will be JSON, but you are returning plain string which is in incorrect format... Try return correct JSON or change content type to plain text for test...

Answer (score -3):

remove this code dataType: 'json' from your code and run

Comment: That is defenitely not the correct answer. datatype has nothing to do with the CORS error.